# This was the first phrase to ...?... into his head

Tags: single-word-requests

What verb best fits here, meaning it was the first form of words that crossed his mind?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that you are looking for the first thing that popped into his head.

Answer (score 3):

As oerkelens says, the verb you are looking for is [*pop*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pop?q=pop#pop__3).

> Make or cause to make a light explosive sound

It is metaphorical, as there is no actual sound, but it is like the idea was in a bubble, which popped while floating through your head.

> The thought popped into my head.

Comment: This isn’t a metaphor; it’s a different definition: “to come or go quickly, suddenly, or unexpectedly, e.g., _She popped into the kitchen to check the stove._” (See [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pop?s=t), definition #3.)

Answer (score 0):

These are expressions that may be used in that context:

- the first thing that jumped into his mind.
- the first thing that occurred to him.
- the first thing that came to his mind.
- the fist thing that sprung (in)to his mind.

Answer (score 0):

Many would not use **entered.**

"This is the first form he considered."